# How get id of mail new

Tags: gmail-api

I'm using gmail api to get id of mail new in five minutes once. I used total mail new minus total mail old to get id of mail new. But Total of mail is very large, time process very long. Is there any algorithm to get id of mail new  that can handle faster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the timestamp when you get new messages and use that in the query next time you list messages.

**Example**

Let's say you list new messages at `Sat Mar 25 2017 21:06:53 GMT+0100 (CET)`. This is the same as `1490472413` seconds since the epoch. Just use this in the next listing with the query `after:1490472413`.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages?q=after:1490472413
```

Comment: Thank you Tholle. I'm trying.